# Changing the destination of R CMD build

Tags: r, package

Is it possible to set a flag in the `R CMD build ...` command which specifies the destination folder for the `tar.gz` file?

I have looked pretty closely at the `R CMD --help` and cannot see it - but i may be missing something.

Comment: This post started life as a series of SO questions to help me build my first R package. I've rolled the lot into a [blog](http://ricardianambivalence.com/2012/07/28/creating-an-r-package-in-10-mins/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be to `cd` to the destination folder and run `R CMD build foo` from there. E.g. sources are in `~/pkgsrcs/foo` and you want `tar.gz` to be in `~/pkgbuild/foo` then:

```
cd ~/pkgbuild/foo
R CMD build ~/pkgsrcs/foo
```

will result in `foo_version.tar.gz` in `~/pkgsrcs/foo`.